# Creating maven project in eclipse Mars doesn't have proper folder structure

Tags: maven, eclipse-mars

I have recently downloaded Eclipse Mars. I'm trying to create a maven project by following this link : http://websystique.com/maven/create-a-maven-web-project-with-eclipse/

I get the folder structure like shown in below image with a red crossed in project name. 
[image]

I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Change to Package Explorer View

Comment: There are nothing wrong with the folder structure. You are in a view that show all resources related to this kind of project.